# Disable Alt+Tab Visual Effect

Tags: windows, tabs, alt-tab

I really like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>, except the only real use I have for it is to effectively move through my windows like I do with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> in Chrome.

Is there any way to disable this visual effect and just have my windows flash like tabs on my computer (I already have all visual effects disabled)?

If this question is chosen to be reopened great, but I did eventually find a solution to this issue:

> [What Registry Key Controls the Alt-Tab Aero Peek (flip2d) Delay?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ebf508d-835f-4603-9dea-5b6bfdeda93e/what-registry-key-controls-the-alttab-aero-peek-flip2d-delay?forum=w7itproui)
>
> - Create `D_WORD` value `LivePreview_ms` with a value of `1` within:
>
>   ```
>   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AltTab
>   ```

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: I believe that this isn’t a duplicate, but I’m voting to leave closed because I don’t understand it (i.e., I believe that it’s Unclear What You’re Asking).   What is it that you want?   The ability to see all your windows in a three-dimensional diagonal array, without any ability to navigate between them?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the effect in Windows + Tab can be disabled, but, if you just want to switch quick, try using Alt + Tab.

Comment: Lol how do I see the entire windows then?  Yes I was aware of that.

Comment: This should really be a comment at best.

Comment: Just because you don't like an answer, doesn't mean it is incorrect... there is no way to disable the effect and Alt+Tab does show a preview of the window.

Comment: So I have been experimenting with alt+tab and it appears if you press it down and wait one entire second or so then press it again it flashes the window on the screen.

Comment: modifying alt+tab preview delay  does seem to work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to disable visual effect in Windows 10

Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> System-> Advanced system settings -> Performance -> Settings

Choose what to disable or use a preset available.